# is return Problem(errorMessage) is the right way to return any kind of error in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Asp.net core web API.

is return Problem(errorMessage) is the right way to return any kind of error in asp.net core if we are not sure about a particular status code.

below is my code,

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] MyModel request)
        {
            var (success,statuscode, errorMessage) = await _service.MyMethod(Id, request);
            return success ? Ok() : Problem(errorMessage, statusCode: statuscode);
        }
```

MyMethod method will either return BadRequest or UnprocessableEntity status code if any error will come.

So,is it a right way to return the error in Problem()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your services shouldn't be coupled directly to HTTP status codes. I'd normally make custom exceptions that the services can throw, and add a global filter that can translate those exceptions to an appropriate HTTP response. Then you don't have to add the same error handling code to every action

Answer (score 0):

For any validation issues, you should return UnprocessableEntity which is 422 if you want to go by the book and add the details on ProblemDetails(check below).
Now, this is not mandatory. At the end of the days your api is a contract between you and your client, and you should define this hand check for your integration. What are you expecting on the server side and what is the client going to receive.
Now for global exceptions you can inject a middleware and capture them and provide a specified details of what happened. In this case you should return a ProblemDetails instance.

[ProblemDetails class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

The [ietf](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807) tried to create a standard by specifying the details of this class.

Now by default when you return this type you should include as well a MediaType, if the request was a get, you should return as part of the headers Accept: application/problem + json
Using a post you will be adding Content-Type:application/problem + json instead.

My recommendation:
Now for Validation issues you can check for ModelState.IsValid and if there is any error of your model it should be on the Errors property.
For exceptions go with the middleware.

Now this is not a blue print. You can extend the class or the customer may use another type of format to process your responses in case of any errors, at the end of the day as I said, this is a contract between you and your client.